# Can we propogate signal from android application to know another user having the same application in android phone

Tags: android, geolocation, cloud, android-geofence, android-webservice

I am building an android app as my project. I need to implement a functionality which can let me know the same types of users (having my application in their phone) around in 1-5 meter distance. Is there anything that i can use or can i propogates any signals to do so. I dont want to connect those users but I am just interested in knowing the presence of my application in the vicinity/area. 
The only thing I am aiming is mapping the users who has same applications. You can consider the below given scenario.

Example: suppose My application is 'TESTAPP'. There are 100 students on a floor, out of those 10 have my application. If one of 10 student turn on the application, then 
1. I want to know that, there are more 9 students present at the same floor.
2. if possible i wan to map them by propogating a signal through 1st user.

Note: I am Creating a cloud based webservice for android and using geolocation.

Comment: How can you tell that there are 10 users when only one activates your app? and why do you want to **spy** them?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein 10 people are just an assumption, and ofcourse I am not spying on them, I might have forgot to mention that, i only wanna know if all 10 users are online on my app. (So that i can send push notification). I am also be asking user permission for  location access. Its just as GPS is not so accurate so if i track all 10 from GPS i cant be sure if all are in the same room, building. So I am thinking if i could search one user from another by some signals around 1 meter, and then i can continue the same with other users. (My Real time scenarion would be having thousands of users)

Comment: If you only want to push a notification, push it. Then, when (if) they connect, they will receive that info. No need to use James Bond  techniques to know who is near who.

Comment: Push notification will be just a part of application, The main aim is to avoid geofence as because of its shape (circular). The application will be accessible to everyone with all functionalities  but the one of those functions/module is only for the users in an event furing few hours. So if user leave the area/vicinity then he will not be able to access that event functionality. I am trying the approach of dynamic functionality despite of the shape. Hence I want to map users and create a geofence accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Bluetooth or WiFi P2P. See http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html

Comment: Cheers, Sounds good !! I will definitely have look into wifi P2P